# ChartJS Grid Lines shouldn't surpass the X Axis (Y = 0) Line & Re-style Y Axis Color and Width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am currently developing a component in which the grid lines on the vertical axis (the only ones present) should stop exactly on the X Axis Lines (Y = 0) line and not surpass this limit.  Something similar to what is going on on the Y Axis (X = 0) on the Image attached, but in this case there are no grid lines at all, the grid lines should be present on the vertical Axis.

Also the style of the X Axis Lines is different to the Y Axis Lines style (Width and Color) and I can't find a way to modify them independently neither in ChartJS Documentation nor in Stackoverflow questions.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add 'tickColor' to 'white'. It should fix it.

Ex:

```
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: true,
          tickColor: 'white'
        },
      }
```